# Поиск и перенос текста между полями в MSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Задача перенести текст с одного поля в другой в одной таблице базы MYSQL.

Поиск текста такого типа:
"images/kontinent/cantry/Ukraine/kiy.jpg" - текст (/kontinent/cantry/Ukraine/kiy.jpg) будет каждый раз другой.

Текст с правками для вставки:
"image_intro":-сюда вставить найденный текст-,

Имя таблицы - ivzbq_content

Поле для поиска - fulltext

Поле для вставки - images

Если есть решение такой задачи, прошу помочь.

Comment: наверняка есть. только вы не указали как именно надо искать.  Берете подходящие функции и с помощью них выражаете как вытащить нужный текст из нужного поля. Пробуете это в select. когда все устраивает переделываете select в `update ivzbq_content set image_intro=ваша_функция_получающая_значение where те_условия_которые_были_в_select`

Comment: напишите примерно команду, как выбрать нужный текст, который каждый раз разный. Пример текста я написал выше

Comment: я из написанного ничего не понял

Comment: Судя по описанию, надо тупо заменить `images/` на `image_intro/`.

Comment: Суть задачи: найти текст в таблице в указанном поле (текст по некоторым параметрам будет меняться), и перенести его в другое поле этой же таблицы.